# How Can i save jquery sortable connected lists in database mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Hey guys I have two connected lists and I don't know how to pass or get values correctly

I have Two list

**The left list**: the value I want to add is "0" which mean it's inactive

**The Right list**: the value that I want to add is "1" which mean it's active
**also with a value position**

[Image for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nWnR.png)

**this is my HTML code:**

```
<h5>inactive fruit</h5>
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">

        <?php foreach($rows as $row){
                        if($row['active'] === '0'){ ?> 
        
            <li class="ui-state-default"><?php echo $row['name']?></li>
        
        <?php   }}?>
</ul>


<h5>Active Market</h5>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">

    <?php foreach($rows as $row){
                        if($row['active'] === '1'){ ?> 
        
            <li class="ui-state-default"><?php echo $row['name']?></li>
        
        <?php   }}?>
</ul>
```

**This is js code:**

```
  <script>
   $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        }).disableSelection();
   } );
  </script>
```

i want to do it with ajax

The Database structure is:

ID (int),

name (varchar),

active (varchar) number 1 means active number 2 means inactive,

posistion(varchar) for the posistion rank

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At what time do you want to send data to the DB? Is there a save button? What is the DB structure, is i d ID based or Position based lists?

Comment: @Twisty yes i want to send it to DB by click function, without button, The DB structure is [ID, name, active, posistion ]

Comment: Ok, click event on what element?

Comment: @Twisty I think if I use element it not gonna work? that exactly my question too, I don't know how to do function to send data after any changes

Comment: Ok, got it, so you do not want send it on a Click event, but rather an Update to either list. Do you have an Update script that should receive the list details and put them into the DB?

Comment: @Twisty thanks, yes i have it's wordpress script to receive the list details, but i don't know to create the ajax code that will send data to my script

Comment: @Twisty thank you so much, you are legand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  function sendData(api, data) {
    $.post(api, data, function(results) {
      console.log(results);
    });
  }
  $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    update: function(event, ui) {
      // This event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.
      var inactive = $("#sortable1").sortable("serialize");
      var active = $("#sortable2").sortable("serialize");
      console.log(inactive, active);
      sendData("updateFruit.php", {
        inactive: inactive,
        active: active
      });
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.column {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.column h5 {
  padding: 0.4em;
  margin: : 0;
}

.column ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.column ul li {
  padding: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="column ui-widget">
  <h5>Inactive fruit</h5>
  <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="fruit-1">Mango</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="fruit-2">Orange</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="fruit-3">Kewi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="column ui-widget">
  <h5>Active Market</h5>
  <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="fruit-4">Banana</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This makes use of a few different options:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update
- https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize
- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Your PHP Script will have to handle the posted data. Something like:

```
<?php

$active = array();
$inactive = array();

if(isset($_POST['active'])){
  $active = json_decode($_POST['active']);
}
if(isset($_POST['active'])){
  $inactive = json_decode($_POST['inactive']);
}

$rows = array();
$count = 0;

foreach($active as $name){
  array_push($rows, array(
    "name" => $name,
    "active" => 1,
    "position": $count++
  ));
}

$count = 0;

foreach($inactive as $name){
  array_push($rows, array(
    "name" => $name,
    "active" => 0,
    "position" => $count++
  ));
}

// Connect to MySQL DB, stored to $mysqli
// Generate Update Code, either unique Statements or one large statement
foreach($rows as $row){
  $mysqli->query("UPDATE fruits SET active = {$row.active}, position = {$row.position} WHERE name = '{$row.name}';);
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Reference:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

This is a basic example and your code will likely be different. This example also does not sanitize the inputs or protect again SQL Injection and should only be used as an basic example. Production code should use all the proper SQL techniques and best practices.